# What's causing undefined method `form' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) when filling in a form with ruby cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am trying to fill in a number of form forms using ruby cucumber and I am getting undefined method `form' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). On the first page it fill out the form correctly but on the second page i get that error messgae.

Code

```
Then /^next page Licence Type: "(.*)", Licence Years: "(.*)", NCD: "(.*)"$/ do |licence_type, licence_years, ncd|
   step 'I wait "1" seconds'
   frame = @browser.frames.find{ |frame| frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").exists? }
   frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").select(:id => "ctl03_content-216088_drivinglicencetype-213533_dd").select licence_type
   frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").select(:id => "ctl03_content-216088_drivinglicenceyears-213534_dd").select licence_years
   frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").select(:id => "ctl03_content-216088_ncd-for-new-models-767231_dd").select ncd
   frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").select(:id => "ctl03_content-216088_nrofclaims-213540_dd").select "None"
   frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").select(:id => "ctl03_content-216088_nrofconvictions-220190_dd").select "None"
   frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").radio(:id => "ctl03_content-216088_usualpaymentmethod-231551_rbRadioList_0").click
   frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047").button(:id => "ctl03_navigation-216089_table-261670_row-261671_next-261674_next-261675_pbNext").click
   step 'I wait "1" seconds'
end


Then /^next page 2 Mileage: "(.*)", Car Value: "(.*)" & Overnight Location: "(.*)"$/ do |mileage, car_value, overnight_location|
  frame = @browser.frames.find{ |frame| frame.form(:method => "post").exists? }
  frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5322").select(:id => "ctl03_content-231405_car-details-231421_annualmileage-231427_dd").select mileage
  frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5322").text_field(:id => "ctl03_content-231405_car-details-231421_vehiclevalue-231426_tb").set car_value
  frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5322").text_field(:id => "ctl03_content-231405_car-details-231421_purchase-date-231428_MONTH").set "01"
  frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5322").text_field(:id => "ctl03_content-231405_car-details-231421_purchase-date-231428_YEAR").set "2008"
  frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5322").select(:id => "ctl03_content-231405_car-details-231421_garage-231424_dd").select overnight_location
  frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5322").button(:id => "ctl03_navigation-231432_copy-of-table-261677_row-261678_next-261681_next-261682_pbNext").click
  step 'The page Assumptions containing the following text'
  frame.form(:action => "post").button(:id => "ctl03_navigation-279445_copy-of-copy-of-table-279454_row-279455_next-279458_next-279459_pbNext").click
  step 'I wait "1" seconds'
  price =  frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5334").div(:id, "premiumprice-882008").exist?
  puts price
  puts assert price.eql? (true)
end
```

Comment: Hi Dawid - I am new to stackover flow and dont know how.

Comment: You can make a block of code by indenting it by 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `frame` is `nil` - it could not find a frame with a form with `:method => "post"`. Perhaps you should be looking for the form by the action `:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5322"` as you do in the first example. Or maybe you need to add the wait step in before looking for it - these are the only differences to your working example that I can see.

Also I'd highly recommend assigning the form to a variable so you don't keep repeating `frame.form(:action => "Default.aspx?Action=nav&Page=5047")` etc - yuk!

Comment: I have tried that and I still get the same issue, I will try changing the form to a variable.